# Need help in custom screen

Tags: acumatica

I have two GI screens, which takes CustomerID as input and show data from different screens. My question is, I want to create a custom screen and add tabs Sales Orders, Invoices, and want to display that GIs data in these tabs. The main purpose is instead of checking data in multiple GI screens want to display all information on one screen.

Answer (score 0):

I have one ways maybe it can help, but i'm  not sure.

First, you create virtual view like `usrGI_CD` or `GI_CD` in `CacheExtension<GI-DAC>`

Next, you handle it in your code like:

```
GI-Graph graph = CreateInstance<GI-Graph>();

GI-DAC giResult = PXSelect<GI-DAC, Where<Field1, Equal<Required<Field1>>>>.Select(graph, valueField1,......);
```

You can add a lots field you want same with `Field1`. After that you will have row of value that you want and you can use PXUIFieldAttribute.SetValue(cache, giResult.value) to set value in your DataView.

Hope this help!